# Compilation problems with custom enumeration

Tags: enumitem

For some reason or other the following code does not compile. Could anyone provide an insight into why?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,hhline,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz,background,array,multicol,bbding}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}

\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupmodenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifmoditem\llap{\mesymbol\enspace}\fi##1}%
    \global\moditemfalse}%
}

\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupcmodenumerate}

\newif\ifcitem
\newcommand{\setupcmodenumerate}{%
  \global\citemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\citem##1{\global\citemtrue\def\cecolor{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifcitem\color{\cecolor}\fi##1}%
    \global\citemfalse}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\moditem{*} test
\citem{blue}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you don't need to load `tikz` if you are loading `background` (`background` internally loads `tikz`).

Comment: The second `\setlist` command overrides the `before=` given with the first one. If you want to use both `\moditem` and `\citem` you need to merge the two codes.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I know tikz is not needed but just included all of my preamble for in case it was needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `\setlist` command overrides the `before=\setupmodenumerate` given with the first, so `\moditem` doesn't get defined. You have to merge the two settings. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,color}

\setlist[enumerate]{before=\setupmodenumerate}

\newif\ifmoditem
\newif\ifcitem
\newcommand{\setupmodenumerate}{%
  \global\moditemfalse
  \global\citemfalse
  \let\origmakelabel\makelabel
  \def\moditem##1{\global\moditemtrue\def\mesymbol{##1}\item}%
  \def\citem##1{\global\citemtrue\def\cecolor{##1}\item}%
  \def\makelabel##1{%
    \origmakelabel{\ifmoditem\llap{\mesymbol\enspace}\else\ifcitem\color{\cecolor}\fi\fi##1}%
    \global\moditemfalse\global\citemfalse}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\moditem{*} test
\citem{blue} test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]