# enumeration lists with special decorations

Tags: lists, enumerate, decorations, annotations

Within an enumerated list, I would like some "meta"-level annotations: Mark a single, specific item in boldface, or another colour, or have an arrow point at it from the left margin, or surround it with a box. But the `\item` macro cannot be embedded within some other macro. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you want to markup the item itself?  Would a macro like `\specialitem` be acceptable?  Or do you want `\item{\highlight ... }`?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87564/10898 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21004/10898

Comment: Alan: \specialitem would be fine.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) to explain more clearly what you want. Comments such as "the `\item` macro cannot be embedded within some other macro" suggest that you may have serious constraints so you should spell out what you need in more detail. it would, for example, be possible to do something that fits your description by modifying the `\item` command except that this might violate your unexplained embedding requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can embed `\item` inside a macro. Below I define `\specialitem` to set an `\item` with the necessary non-argument formatting specified via `\setspecialitem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setspecialitem}[1]{\def\specialitem@{#1}}
\newcommand{\specialitem}{%
  \begingroup
  \specialitem@
  \item\leavevmode
  \endgroup
}
\setspecialitem{}% Default
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
  \item First

  \setspecialitem{\color{red}}
  \specialitem Second

  \setspecialitem{\itshape}
  \specialitem Third

  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It would also be possible to do more complex things (like boxing a special number). Here's one showing a `\boxeditem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxeditem}{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \let\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \oldlabelenum@\expandafter\csname labelenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth\endcsname
  \@namedef{labelenum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}{\fbox{\oldlabelenum@}}
  \item\leavevmode%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First

  \boxeditem Second

  \boxeditem Third

  \boxeditem Fourth

  \item Last
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```